# how to change the bouncing range of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView that hides a view that is underneath it. when you scroll the tableview to it ends, you can scroll even more and then you see the views that are under the tableview..
the range that you can extra scroll is fixed, and when you reach it the tableview bounces back to it's original position..

is there any way to set this range? i would like to increase it inorder to show a long view under the tableview, about half the screen, and the tableview can be extra scrolled a little less..

Comment: Do you mean the 'bouncy scroll'? This is indeed fixed! No app should ever change this behavior. I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish here, but a view hiding beneath the table view sounds a bit weird in my opinion. Did you ever consider using the table header view? See `tableHeaderView` in the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: think of a water mark that is embedded in the background of the screen. it is revealed when you scroll the tableview more than it's end. the thing is that my watermark is a little larger than the maximum of the extra bounce. i can not decrease the watermark size..

Comment: because of design related issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to setup the bouncing range of tableview. Alternative way is to add pan gesture recognizer to mock bouncing. Of course you need set tableview's property bounces to NO at first.